# Does MapReduce on a single node machine make sense?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Traditional definitions of MapReduce state that it is a "programming model for processing large data sets with a parallel, distributed algorithm on a cluster."

Over the weekend, I was trying out MongoDB and tried a few simple MapReduce queries. (The basic word count problem in a book). MongoDB performed really well, but then I began to wonder if it was actually a MapReduce operation, or just a simple group-by aggregation, hence my question:

In case of a single-node "cluster", does it make sense to use MapReduce?

Comment: If there are views of the data that cannot be represented through normal queries or the aggregation framework, then yes, it may make sense. Beyond that ... this seems to be an opinion question?

Answer (score 0):

> Traditional definitions of MapReduce state that it is a "programming model for processing large data sets with a parallel, distributed algorithm on a cluster."

Well i does not need to be on a cluster, a single node can implement map and reduce functions with threads or processes. I do not know the inner dynamics in the mongodb while doing map reduce, but i know map reduce in MongoDB does not have the same dynamics as Hadoop.

> In case of a single-node "cluster", does it make sense to use MapReduce?

For large amount of data map and reduce functions need to be executed in a distributed environment so no i does not make sense to process big data(for small sized data it is OK).

**Opinion**

Sorry it section will be not an answer but statement open to discussion. In a software system MongoDB s responsibilty should be to keep data not to process it. If there is a data processing requirement(will be 99%) MongoDB MapReduce can be used until a certain amount of data size(import to determine threshold before hand), then should be propagated to a Hadoop cluster.(or a similar distributed solution)

Comment: I don't follow your answer, or why you're pushing Hadoop?

Comment: Just pointing out map reduce itself does not relate to distribution of server nodes but workers. Workers can be processes or thread in a single machine or dedicated servers. About pushing hadoop i intentionally defined it under a opinion title. As i said the statement is open to discussion.

Comment: Just updated statement see paranthesis, preventing promoting a single tool or software as the only solution.